# "Against whom" vs "Whom against"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion, pied-piping

1. **Against whom** are you playing?
2. **Whom against** are you playing?
3. (Some better way to say this)

Can anyone explain which sentence is the exactly correct one, or provide one that is? Does the order  of the words *whom* and *against* really matter in this sentence?

Comment: Why is the word *against* involved here at all? Seems redundant, maybe even pleonastic, in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically correct are: "Against whom are you playing?" (in the very formal English), "Whom are you playing against?.

These questions derive from statements: "He is the man against whom I am playing", "He is the man whom (or who) I am playing against". "Whom" is a complement of a preposition "against". A preposition can precede its complement or be moved to the end-position.

Comment: Most people would simply say, "Who[m] are you playing [against]?" Pied piping is a learnèd affectation that sounds stilted and artificial.

Comment: @Tchrist "Whom are you playing?" - Can it be possible that a non-native speaker (or a native speaker) would take this in as: "Whom are you playing (with)?" and would answer "I'm playing with my brother (against his fellows)". Thank you.